# Why I am printing XPS file to receipt printer but get raw file content on paper instead?

Tags: c#, xps

I am trying to print out a XPS file to my receipt printer (EPSON TM-T88IV Receipt). I am using PrintQueue to print the document which is read from a memory stream. It works well at most of times, but sometimes, it prints out the raw file content instead of what it should be.

Here is my code for printing XPS:

```
public class XpsPrinterHelper
    {
        public bool Print(byte[] documentImage, string printerName, string tempXpsFilename = "report.xps")
        {
            var success = false;
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (var printerQueue = GetPrintQueueFromPrinterName(printerName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //save file temporary
                        var filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), tempXpsFilename);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, documentImage);
                        using (var printSystemJobInfo = printerQueue.AddJob())
                        {
                            printSystemJobInfo.JobStream.Write(documentImage, 0, documentImage.Length);
                        }
                        success = true;
                    }
                    catch (PrintJobException)
                    {
                        printerQueue.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join(); //Wait until finished
            return success;
        }

        private static PrintQueue GetPrintQueueFromPrinterName(string printerName)
        {
            if (printerName.StartsWith(@"\\")) //If it is a shared printer
            {
                var serverPath = printerName.Substring(0, printerName.LastIndexOf('\\'));
                var sharedPrinterName = printerName.Replace(serverPath, "");
                var printServer = new PrintServer(serverPath.TrimEnd('\\'));
                return printServer.GetPrintQueue(sharedPrinterName.Trim('\\'));
            }

            var localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
            return localPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName);
        }
    }
```

But sometimes the result likes a trash 
[image]

I really appreciate anyone point out what happened or give me suggestion to solve this issue.